# Troubleshooting playing video with PHP, downloads instead of playing

Tags: php

(Disclosure: I previously posted about my issue and got part of the way there, and ended up closing the question before I confirmed it working, which is my mistake. I have included all of the original question along with an edit so that the scope of what I'm trying to accomplish is understood).

I'm a bit rusty with my PHP and decided to pick up a new project after a while of being away. I'm attempting to create a page with PHP and HTML on apache to display videos dynamically.

I successfully got the video titles displayed on a main page, along with an ajax post to a parse file to dynamically get the link for said video. My questions is now that I have the link to the video on its attached drive, how can I code this within PHP so it will display the video(without moving the videos directory under the root www).

I'm the type of person that doesn't like to be spoon fed, and I've looked around and understood the basic concept of $_GET, and I understand it to get images, but I don't seem to grasp how to make this work for videos.

Basically the file structure I have:

File 1 - (root www)/main.php (main page, not really associated with the issue)

File 1 - (root www)/videotype1.php (used to dynamically show this type of videos, with div ready to display the video ready when the specific source is selected)

File 2 - /mnt/drive/videos/video.mp4 (the video I want to access).

I'm just asking for a basic idea of how to approach it for me to go into further research on how to actually do it, because I'm quite stumped at the moment. If there is a post or somewhere that explains how to do this for a video I'll gladly look into it, but I couldn't find much luck for videos.

Thanks

Edit 1: implemented the suggestion from Magnus, where I feel like I am on the right track. I did slightly modify it from video/avi to video/mp4 as that is the file type. It attempts to download the file instead of displaying it like I am trying. What would be the way to not download the file and properly insert it into a video src? I'm really struggling with this project. Here is the basic structure I have, what did I do wrong here?

```
$mainFile = $_COOKIE['selecPath']."/".$_COOKIE['selecVid'];
header('Content-type: video/mp4');
        if(file_exists($mainFile))
        {
                header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="video.mp4"');
                readfile($mainFile);
        }
    echo "<video width='1280' height='720' controls>";
    echo "<source src='video.mp4' type='video/mp4'>";
    echo "Your browser does not support the video tag.";
    echo "</video>";
```

Another thing I found and tested was header('Content-type: '.mime_content_type($mainFile)); but that didn't really change anything. Is there any clear point within my code that I clearly did wrong? (file_exists was added just as a precaution and there is more code for the checking section which has been redacted, and the code has been tested without it to no change). Essentially the error is as soon as I visit the php page (I am using cookies to hold the data) it automatically asks where to download the file. It is successfully reading the right file, but as a test I let it download and I couldn't even play the file. The file sizes were correct when downloaded so I feel I'm close to the answer.

Comment: The [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header the way you've used it signals a downloadable file, that's why it's downloading it.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm used to a lot of mathematics and logic with php and this is my first dive into video streaming on my own home network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into this [PHP class for video stream](https://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you! I can get this class and modify it to my needs! Working with it immediately solved my problem.